# Can you change the string of an instanced string class

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, class, object

I have this class:

```
class A(str):            
    def __str__(self):
        return "the string"
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return "the repr"

a = A("change me")
```

Running `print a` returns `the string`

Running `repr(a)` returns `the repr`

Running `a` returns `change me`

#### The problem

Running the instance `a` returns the string used to instantiate the class.  How can I change this string in the instance after instantiation?

The returns of `__str__` and `__repr___` are not the problem, as in certain situations rather than calling these methods the instance is called directly. So where you may expect `__repr__` to return, the instance returns the instantiation string instead.

I have been unable to find any attributes within the string class to change this. Most solutions I've tried require you to re-instance the `a` variable, which I don't want to do. I want to change the string from within the current instance of the object class variable.

I have tried rebuilding the class through methods utilising `__new__` and `type()`. However, this seems to require re-instancing the stored class variable, as recreating the class creates a duplicate and does not update the current instance.

I am limited to using Python 2.7, due to pipeline constraints.

Comment: Do you basically want a mutable string subclass? If so, do either of the following answer your question? [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520298/modify-subclassed-string-in-place) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572624/mutable-strings-in-python)

Comment: The 1st reference didn't work for me; using `StringIO` returns an `instance` when running `a`, `<__main__.DelimitedStringIO instance at 0x00000245933C8788>`. However the 2nd link you provided might be working for me...

Comment: Ah, no. :/ Subclassing this as an `Object` returns the object class instance MutableString rather than a string, as a subclass of `string` would. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Since you're using Python 2, `UserString.MutableString` is available. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a potential answer, although it feels VERY bad and hacky.

```
class A(str):            
    def __str__(self):
        return "the string"

    def __repr__(self):
        return "the repr"
    
    def _instance_name(self):
        return [k for k, v in globals().items() if v is self]
    
    def change(self, new_string):
        name = self._instance_name()

        if name:
            globals()[name[0]] = type('A', (A, ), self.__dict__)(new_string)

a = A("change me")
```

Running `a` returns `change me`

```
a.change("I have changed")
```

Running `a` returns `I have changed`

Changing globals this way feels like welcoming the end times, but it's the only solution I've found so far. Any other potential methods would be appreciated!